# Sublime Text 3 Linter not working

Tags: php, sublimetext3

I am trying to establish SublimeLinter for SL3 but it is not working no matter what settings I do.

Here what I am having in user config file

```
{
    "sublimelinter": true,
    "sublimelinter_executable_map":
    {
        "php": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"
    },
}
```

No live error checking or no error checking on file save.

Answer (score 1):

The new version of SublimeLinter3 requires both the base SublimeLinter package (which you have), and a language-specific linter package (which you may not have installed). There are [several ones for PHP](https://sublime.wbond.net/search/sublimelinter%20php), it looks like the most popular currently is [`SublimeLinter-php`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter-php), which uses `php -l` for linting. Install the plugin you want via Package Control, restart Sublime just for fun, and you should now be able to lint your PHP code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. but I am unable to find SublimeLinter-php from install manager. And I am confused with `php -l` where I should add this line?

Answer (score 1):

I made it work this way (Sublime Text 3):

1. Go to Preferences > Package Settings > Sublime Linter > Settings
2. Add this code with your php.exe path

```js
// SublimeLinter Settings - User
{
    "paths": {
        "windows": ["C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php7.2.14"]
    }
}
```

For example if you're using wamp with php7.2.14

[Take a look at the documentation site](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#adding-to-the-paths-setting)

Answer (score 0):

Check Preferences > Settings - User. It could be in your list of ignored packages.

Comment: Nope, it's not been set anything there but theme and tab size only.